# Striking thru a tabular row in LaTeX

Tags: tables, text-decorations

Neither `ulem` nor `soul` packages allow striking thru a whole row in a tabular environment, eg:

```
\sout{1,3-Cyclopentadiene    & 161.39    & 148.19    & 155.65    & 153.43    & 154.7     & 5.5  & 118.20} \\
```

Is there an alternative?

Package `xcolor` with the table option `clashes` with package `dcolumn` so that does not appear to be an option

Answer (score 5):

As a quick and dirty fix you can superpose a row with a `\hline` by reducing row spacing before and after the line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
aaaaa & bbbbb & ccccc \\
11111 & 22222 & 33333 \\ [-1.5ex]
\hline \\ [-1.5ex]
xxxxx & yyyyy & zzzzz \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not ideal, but clever and quick.  +1

Answer (score 3):

One can use TikZ to do so :

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{na} = [shape=rectangle,inner sep=0pt]

\newcommand{\ptStrikeA}[1]{     % Left 'point' to be striked (A)
    \tikz[baseline=(A.base)]\node[na](A){#1};
  }
\newcommand{\ptStrikeB}[1]{     % Right 'point' to be striked (B)
    \tikz[baseline=(B.base)]\node[na](B){#1};
  }  

\newcommand{\strike}{   % Strike from A to B
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \draw (A.west) -- (B.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
                    aaaaa & bbbbb & ccccc \\
        \ptStrikeA{11111} & 22222 & \ptStrikeB{33333} \\
                    xxxxx & yyyyy & zzzzz \\
    \end{tabular}
    \strike
\end{document}
```

This way, you can either strike an entire row, or only part of it. Putting the `\strike` command outside the environment allows you to embed it into beamer overlays.

Answer (score 1):

[Extending the answer given by Dorian]

To achieve multiple strikethroughs in a single table, rather than declaring more and more commands, you can specify the start/end points dynamically:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{na} = [shape=rectangle,inner sep=0pt]

% end point for strike
\newcommand{\ptStrike}[2]{    
    \tikz[baseline=(#1.base)]\node[na](#1){#2};
}

% draw strike between two endpoints
\newcommand{\strike}[2]{  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \draw (#1.west) -- (#2.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        aaaaa & bbbbb & ccccc \\
        \ptStrike{A}{11111} & 22222 & \ptStrike{B}{33333} \\
        xxxxx & yyyyy & zzzzz \\
        \ptStrike{C}{33333333} & 55555555 & \ptStrike{D}{88888888}\\
    \end{tabular}
    \strike{A}{B} % draw strike from A to B
    \strike{C}{D} % draw strike from C to D
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Extending the answer given by @Dorian and @Dixie]

You can take it one step further even and avoid needing to redefine names for beginning and endpoints!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{na} = [shape=rectangle,inner sep=0pt]

\newcommand{\myStrikeBegin}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(begin.base)]\node[na](begin){#1};
}

\newcommand{\myStrikeEnd}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(end.base)]\node[na](end){#1};
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
          \draw (begin.north west) -- (end.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        aaaaa & bbbbb & ccccc \\
        \myStrikeBegin{11111} & 22222 & \myStrikeEnd{33333} \\
        xxxxx & yyyyy & zzzzz \\
        \myStrikeBegin{33333333} & 55555555 & \myStrikeEnd{88888888} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: compiled sample]

Comment: Please, can you edit your answer? Missing `\documentclass`. Thank you.

Comment: @Sebastiano didn't know it was necessary, I guess it is easier to copy it now

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you can easily strike a row with TikZ by using the nodes created by `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{lll}[hvlines]
    aaaaa & bbbbb & ccccc \\
    11111 & 22222 & 33333 \\
    xxxxx & yyyyy & zzzzz \\
    33333333 & 55555555 & 88888888 \\
\CodeAfter
   \tikz \draw [red] (2.5-|1) -- (2.5-|last) ; 
   \tikz \draw [thick,red] ([yshift=-4pt]4-|1) -- ([yshift=4pt]5-|last) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]