# strike out an entire line in table

Tags: tables

I want to strike out an entire line in a table.

A not nice looking solution is to use `soul` package and strike out the text in each cell.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabls}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}


\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ lcc|cc|cc|cc|cc }
\cmidrule{2-11}          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1 week}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{2 weeks}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{3 weeks}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{4 weeks}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{5 weeks}} \\
\cmidrule{2-11} 
\cmidrule{2-11}    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & $<\rho>$ & \#vals. & $<\rho>$ & \#vals. & $<\rho>$ & \#vals. & $<\rho>$ & \#vals. & $<\rho>$ & \#vals. \\
    \hline
    \st{Bridging Centrality} & \st{0.38}  & \st{2}     & \st{0.52}  & \st{3}     & \st{0.48}  & \st{6}     & \st{0.52}  & \st{12}    & \st{0.45}  & \st{5} \\
    \hline
    Bridging Centrality & 0.38  & 2    & 0.52  & 3     & 0.48  & 6     & 0.52  & 12    & 0.45  & 5 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \caption{$<\rho>$ is the mean of the correlation coefficients that have a significant ($<0.05$) p-value. \#vals indicates the number (out of 20) of correlation coefficient that are significant.}
\end{sidewaystable}%

\end{document}
```

Is there something better out there?

Comment: Duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276738/striking-thru-a-tabular-row-in-latex

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156162/strike-out-a-table-cell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do it, without `soul`: a simple `\hline` and a`\vspace`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabls}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}

 \begin{document}


\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ lcc|cc|cc|cc|cc }
\cmidrule{2-11} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1 week}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{2 weeks}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{3 weeks}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{4 weeks}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{5 weeks}} \\
\cmidrule{2-11}
\cmidrule{2-11} \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & $<\rho>$ & \#vals. & $<\rho>$ & \#vals. & $<\rho>$ & \#vals. & $<\rho>$ & \#vals. & $<\rho>$ & \#vals. \\
    \hline
    Bridging Centrality & 0.38 & 2 & 0.52 & 3 & 0.48 & 6 & 0.52 & 12 & 0.45 & 5 \\[-2.2ex]
    \hline\noalign{\vspace{\dimexpr 2.2ex-\doublerulesep}}
    \hline
    Bridging Centrality & 0.38 & 2 & 0.52 & 3 & 0.48 & 6 & 0.52 & 12 & 0.45 & 5 \\
\hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \caption{$<\rho>$ is the mean of the correlation coefficients that have a significant ($<0.05$) p-value. \#vals indicates the number (out of 20) of correlation coefficient that are significant.}
\end{sidewaystable}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wish `latexdiff` would use this!

Comment: What does `\noalign` do exactly?

Comment: @cfr: Without it, using `\vspace{\dimexpr ...}` leads to an error message  `misplaced \noalign`.

Comment: @cfr `\noalign` inserts vertical mode material between the rows of a table, it underlies `\halign` and booktabs spacing and `\rowcolor` and other stuff.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you both. So why does it say there's a misplaced `\noalign` when there isn't one?

Comment: @cfr `\halign` starts with `\noalign` and it has to be the first thing in the row, `\\ (anything) \hline` will give that error, but `\\ \noalign{anything) \hline` doesn't start the row before `\hline`

Comment: Not that this solution, while easy and convenient, does not work if text inside a cell needs multiple lines!

Answer (score 2):

In an environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you can easily draw whatever rule you wish with TikZ and the nodes created in the array by `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
\centering
\newcolumntype{'}{!{\vrule}}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ lcc'cc'cc'cc'cc }
    \cmidrule{2-11} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1 week}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{2 weeks}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{3 weeks}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{4 weeks}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{5 weeks}} \\
    \cmidrule{2-11}
    \cmidrule{2-11} \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & $\langle\rho\rangle$ & \#vals. & $\langle\rho\rangle$ & \#vals. & $\langle\rho\rangle$ & \#vals. & $\langle\rho\rangle$ & \#vals. & $\langle\rho\rangle$ & \#vals. \\
    \hline
    Bridging Centrality & 0.38 & 2 & 0.52 & 3 & 0.48 & 6 & 0.52 & 12 & 0.45 & 5 \\
    \hline
    Bridging Centrality & 0.38 & 2 & 0.52 & 3 & 0.48 & 6 & 0.52 & 12 & 0.45 & 5 \\
    \hline
\CodeAfter
   \tikz \draw [red,double] (3.5-|1) -- (3.5-|last) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\caption{$\langle\rho\rangle$ is the mean of the correlation coefficients that have a significant ($<0.05$) p-value. \#vals
  indicates the number (out of 20) of correlation coefficient that are significant.} 
\end{sidewaystable}%

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]