# Strikeout of a table row and caption two tables separately

Tags: tables, line, nicematrix, strikeout

First question. I want to organize these two tabular as subtables (a) and (b) of a main table and share a single  caption.

Second question. I want to cross out the second row of the first subtable with a red line.

Can anyone help me?

'''

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\columncolor{bluepoli!40}}}

\begin{tabular}{|Bc| c c c c c c c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{bluepoli!40}

    \textbf{\footnotesize    Patient} & Varus angle [°] & Posterior slope [°] & Body Weight [kg] & Body Weight [N] & $-F_z$ (HIGH100) [N] & $-F_z$ (Individual) [N] & Weight Factor [/] \T\B\\
    \hline
   \textbf{\footnotesize     K1L} & 3 & 5 & 105 & 1030 & 4136.8 & 3587.1 & 0.92\T\B\\
    \textbf{\footnotesize    K2L} & 5 & 11 & 92 & 903 & 4138.1 & 3655.3 & 0.94 \T\B\\
    \textbf{\footnotesize    K3R} & 3.5 & 10 & 98 & 960 & 4152.8 & 2887.9 & 0.74 \T\B \\
    \textbf{\footnotesize   K5R} & 1 & 7 & 96 & 942 & 3508.4 & 3374.5 & 0.86 \T\B \\
    \textbf{\footnotesize    K6L} & -4 & 7 & 83 & 814 & 4060.3 & 2970.9 & 0.76 \T\B\\
    \textbf{\footnotesize   K7L} & 6.5 & 7 & 69 & 678 & 3488.3 & 2146.8 & 0.55 \T\B\\
    \textbf{\footnotesize   K8L} & 4 & 11 & 79 & 775 & 3542.8 & 2109.7 & 0.54 \T\B\\
    \textbf{\footnotesize   K9L} & 7 & 6 & 109 & 1070 & 2938.5 & 2182.6 & 0.56 \T\B\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{}

\bigskip
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\columncolor{bluepoli!40}}}
\begin{tabular}{|Bc| c c c c c c c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{bluepoli!40}

   \textbf{\footnotesize    Patient} & Varus angle [°] & Posterior slope [°] & Body Weight [kg] & Body Weight [N] & $-F_z$ (HIGH100) [N] & $-F_z$ (Individual) [N] & Weight Factor [/] \T\B\\
    \hline
    \textbf{\footnotesize    K1L} & 3 & 5 & 105 & 1030 & 2646.3 & 2436.1 & 0.86 \T\B\\
    \textbf{\footnotesize    K2L} & 5 & 11 & 92 & 903 & 2830.9 & 1948.4 & 0.69 \T\B\\
    \textbf{\footnotesize    K3R} & 3.5 & 10 & 98 & 960 & 2762.4 & 1987.7 & 0.7 \T\B \\
    \textbf{\footnotesize   K5R} & 1 & 7 & 96 & 942 & 2935.1 & 1996.5 & 0.7 \T\B \\
    \textbf{\footnotesize    K6L} & -4 & 7 & 83 & 814 & 3034.1 & 2187.6 & 0.86 \T\B\\
    \textbf{\footnotesize   K7L} & 6.5 & 7 & 69 & 678 & 2414.4 & 1666.9 & 0.59 \T\B\\
    \textbf{\footnotesize   K8L} & 4 & 11 & 79 & 775 & 2741 & 1631.4 & 0.58 \T\B\\
    \textbf{\footnotesize   K9L} & 7 & 6 & 109 & 1070 & 3359 & 2149.7 & 0.76 \T\B\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}}

\caption{Table in which the \emph{Weight Factors} are depicted as the ratio between the first load peak of the activity and the corresponding one in the average \emph{HIGH100} data. In figure a) the stair descending activity is shown while in figure b) the walking exercise can be seen. In both cases the patient highlighted in red was considered an outlier for the following calculations.}
\label{tab:WF_tab}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete, compilable small document. What column type is `B`?

Answer (score 2):

**(1)** First question. To have two `subtables` (a) and (b) sharing a single caption the following structure might be used together with the package `subcaption`:

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering  
    \begin{subtable}{\linewidth}    
        \footnotesize \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c| c c c c c c c|}     
        ...
        \end{tabular}
        \subcaption{Subtable I}\label{subtab:a}
    \end{subtable}% 
    \bigskip
    
    \begin{subtable}{\linewidth}    
        \footnotesize \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c| c c c c c c c|}     
        ...
        \end{tabular}
        \subcaption{Subtable II}\label{subtab:b}
    \end{subtable}%
        \caption{Table in which the \emph{Weight Factors} are depicted  ...}
        \label{tab:WF_tab}
\end{table}
```

**(2)** Making the table fit into the page with a readable font required more changes, mostly using three lines for the header (package `makecell`) and simplifying the column definitions (package `array`). Also added the package `siunitx` to include proper SI units.

**(3)** Second question. The solution for  strikeout an entire row was taken from [strikeout a entire row](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/488910/161015)

Mark the start of the red line with `\StrikeStarts{<cell contents>}` and the end with `\StrikeEnds{<cell contents>}`

The (semi) final result

[image: cc]

This is the code used.

(Still needed is to make the tabular automatically fit the width of the text, align the decimal points, improve the "lines", but those things are beyond the scope of the questions)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{makecell} % newlines in cell
\renewcommand\theadalign{tc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\usepackage{siunitx} % SI units
\usepackage{subcaption}% subtables

\newcolumntype{C}[2]{>{\bfseries\columncolor{#1}\centering}p{#2}}   
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}

\usepackage{showframe}

% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/488910/161015
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{na} = [shape=rectangle,inner sep=0pt]

\newcommand{\StrikeStarts}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(begin.base)]\node[na](begin){#1};
}

\newcommand{\StrikeEnds}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(end.base)]\node[na](end){#1};
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \draw[red] (begin.west) -- (end.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2} % expand the cells vertically
    
    \begin{subtable}{\linewidth}    
    \footnotesize \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|C{blue!10}{1.5cm}| c c c c c c c|}     
            \hline
            \rowcolor{blue!10}          
            \thead{\\Patient } &
            \thead{ Varus \\angle \\ \unit{[\degree]} } &
            \thead{Posterior\\ slope \\ \unit{[\degree]} } &
            \thead{ Body \\ Weight \\ \unit{[\kilogram]}} &
            \thead{Body \\Weight  \\ \unit{[\newton]}} &
            \thead{ $-F_z$ \\(HIGH100) \\ \unit{[\newton]} }&
            \thead{$-F_z$ \\ (Individual)\\ \unit{[\newton]}} &
            \thead{Weight \\Factor\\ \unit{[/]} }\\
            \hline
            K1L&3   &5  &105&1030   &2646.3 &2436.1 &0.86\\
    \StrikeStarts{K2L}&5    &11 &92 &903    &2830.9 &1948.4 &\StrikeEnds{0.69}\\
            K3R&3.5 &10 &98 &960    &2762.4 &1987.7 &0.7\\
            K5R&1   &7  &96 &942    &2935.1 &1996.5 &0.7\\
            K6L&-4  &7  &83 &814    &3034.1&2187.6  &0.86\\
            K7L&6.5 &7  &69 &678    &2414.4 &1666.9 &0.59\\
            K8L&4   &11 &79 &775    &2741   &1631.4 &0.58\\
            K9L&7   &6  &109        &1070   &3359   &2149.7&0.76\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \subcaption{Subtable I}\label{subtab:a}
    \end{subtable}%

\bigskip
    
    \begin{subtable}{\linewidth}    
    \footnotesize \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|C{blue!10}{1.5cm}| c c c c c c c|}     
        \hline
        \rowcolor{blue!10}          
        \thead{\\Patient } &
        \thead{ Varus \\angle \\ \unit{[\degree]} } &
        \thead{Posterior\\ slope \\ \unit{[\degree]} } &
        \thead{ Body \\ Weight \\ \unit{[\kilogram]}} &
        \thead{Body \\Weight  \\ \unit{[\newton]}} &
        \thead{ $-F_z$ \\(HIGH100) \\ \unit{[\newton]} }&
        \thead{$-F_z$ \\ (Individual)\\ \unit{[\newton]}} &
        \thead{Weight \\Factor\\ \unit{[/]} }\\
        \hline
        K1L&3   &5  &105&1030   &2646.3 &2436.1 &0.86\\
        K2L&5   &11 &92 &903    &2830.9 &1948.4 &0.69\\
        K3R&3.5 &10 &98 &960    &2762.4 &1987.7 &0.7\\
        K5R&1   &7  &96 &942    &2935.1 &1996.5 &0.7\\
        K6L&-4  &7  &83 &814    &3034.1&2187.6  &0.86\\
        K7L&6.5 &7  &69 &678    &2414.4 &1666.9 &0.59\\
        K8L&4   &11 &79 &775    &2741   &1631.4 &0.58\\
        K9L&7   &6  &109        &1070   &3359   &2149.7&0.76\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \subcaption{Subtable II}\label{subtab:b}
\end{subtable}%
        \caption{Table in which the \emph{Weight Factors} are depicted as the ratio between the first load peak of the activity and the corresponding one in the average \emph{HIGH100} data. In table (a) the stair descending activity is shown while in table (b) the walking exercise can be seen. In both cases the patient highlighted in red was considered an outlier for the following calculations.}
        \label{tab:WF_tab}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

The package `nicematrix` , that works with tikz node is able to manage the strikeout and also the `X` columns, the `S` columns and the new line inside the cell (command `\Block`). This is an example:

[image: d]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  
\usepackage{siunitx} % SI units
\usepackage{subcaption}% subtables
\usepackage[left=3.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{nicematrix} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering\footnotesize
    \begin{subtable}{\linewidth}    
    \centering\footnotesize
    \sisetup{table-format = 2.2, table-alignment-mode = format}
    \begin{NiceTabular}[width=\linewidth]{>{\bfseries\columncolor{blue!10}}c  S[table-number-alignment = center]  c  X[c]  X[c] X[2,c] X[2,c] S[table-number-alignment = center]}[cell-space-top-limit=4pt,cell-space-bottom-limit=2pt]     
            \hline
            \rowcolor{blue!10}\RowStyle{\bfseries}      
            \Block{}{Patient } &
            \Block{}{Varus \\angle \\ \unit{[\degree]} } &
            \Block{}{Posterior\\ slope \\ \unit{[\degree]} } &
            \Block{}{Body \\ Weight \\ \unit{[\kilogram]}} &
            \Block{}{Body \\Weight  \\ \unit{[\newton]}} &
            \Block{}{$-F_z$ \\(HIGH100) \\ \unit{[\newton]} }&
            \Block{}{$-F_z$ \\ (Individual)\\ \unit{[\newton]}} &
            \Block{}{Weight \\Factor\\ \unit{[/]} }\\
            \hline
            K1L&3   &5  &105&1030   &2646.3 &2436.1 &0.86\\
            K2L&5   &11 &92 &903    &2830.9 &1948.4 &0.69\\
            K3R&3.5 &10 &98 &960    &2762.4 &1987.7 &0.7\\
            K5R&1   &7  &96 &942    &2935.1 &1996.5 &0.7\\
            K6L&-4  &7  &83 &814    &3034.1&2187.6  &0.86\\
            K7L&6.5 &7  &69 &678    &2414.4 &1666.9 &0.59\\
            K8L&4   &11 &79 &775    &2741   &1631.4 &0.58\\
            K9L&7   &6  &109        &1070   &3359   &2149.7&0.76\\
            \hline
            \CodeAfter
            \tikz \draw [red] (3.5-|1) -- (3.5-|9);     % strikeout <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<          
        \end{NiceTabular}
        \subcaption{Subtable I}\label{subtab:a}
    \end{subtable}%

    \bigskip
    
    \begin{subtable}{\linewidth}    
    entering\footnotesize   
    \subcaption{Subtable II}\label{subtab:b}
    \end{subtable}%
        \caption{Table in which the \emph{Weight Factors} are depicted as the ratio between the first load peak of the activity and the corresponding one in the average \emph{HIGH100} data. In table (a) the stair descending activity is shown while in table (b) the walking exercise can be seen. In both cases the patient highlighted in red was considered an outlier for the following calculations.}
            \label{tab:WF_tab}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

By use of the `tabularray` (with libraries `booktabs` and  `siunitx`), `subcaption` and `tikz` with library `tikzmark`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4}%
\subfloat[Case A]{%
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {|X[l, m, font=\bfseries]
                         Q[c,m,si={table-format=-1.1}]|
                         Q[c,m,si={table-format=2}]
                         Q[c,m,si={table-format=3}]
                         Q[c,m,si={table-format=4}]
                    *{2}{Q[c,m,si={table-format=4.1}]}
                         Q[c,m,si={table-format=1.2}]|
                       },
              colsep = 3.3pt,
              row{1} = {font=\small, bg=cyan9}
            }
    \toprule
Patient
    & {{{Varus\\ angle\\ {[\si{\degree}]} }}}
            & {{{Posterior\\ slope\\ {[\si{\degree}]} }}}
                 & {{{Body\\ Weight\\ {[\si{\kilo\gram}]} }}}
                        & {{{Body\\ Weight\\ {[\si{\newton}]} }}}
                              & {{{$-F_z$\\ (HIGH100)\\ {[\si{\newton}]} }}}
                                       & {{{$-F_z$ \\ (Individual)\\ {[\si{\newton}]} }}}
                                                & {{{Weight\\ Factor}}}   \\
K1L &  3    &  5 & 105 & 1030 & 4136.8 & 3587.1 & 0.92  \\
\tikzmarknode{a}{K2L} 
    &  5    & 11 &  92 &  903 & 4138.1 & 3655.3 & 0.94  \\
K3R &  3.5  & 10 &  98 &  960 & 4152.8 & 2887.9 & 0.74  \\
K5R &  1    &  7 &  96 &  942 & 3508.4 & 3374.5 & 0.86  \\
K6L & -4    &  7 &  83 &  814 & 4060.3 & 2970.9 & 0.76  \\
K7L &  6.5  &  7 &  69 &  678 & 3488.3 & 2146.8 & 0.55  \\
K8L &  4    & 11 &  79 &  775 & 3542.8 & 2109.7 & 0.54  \\
K9L &  7    &  6 & 109 & 1070 & 2938.5 & 2182.6 & 0.56  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    }

\medskip
\subfloat[Case B]{%
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {|X[l, m, font=\bfseries]
                         Q[c,m,si={table-format=-1.1}]|
                         Q[c,m,si={table-format=2}]
                         Q[c,m,si={table-format=3}]
                         Q[c,m,si={table-format=4}]
                    *{2}{Q[c,m,si={table-format=4.1}]}
                         Q[c,m,si={table-format=1.2}]|
                       },
              colsep = 3.3pt,
              row{1} = {font=\small, bg=cyan9}
            }
    \toprule
Patient
    & {{{Varus\\ angle\\ {[\si{\degree}]} }}}
            & {{{Posterior\\ slope\\ {[\si{\degree}]} }}}
                 & {{{Body\\ Weight\\ {[\si{\kilo\gram}]} }}}
                        & {{{Body\\ Weight\\ {[\si{\newton}]} }}}
                              & {{{$-F_z$\\ (HIGH100)\\ {[\si{\newton}]} }}}
                                       & {{{$-F_z$ \\ (Individual)\\ {[\si{\newton}]} }}}
                                                & {{{Weight\\ Factor}}}   \\
    \midrule
K1L &  3    &  5 & 105 & 1030 & 4136.8 & 3587.1 & 0.92  \\
K1L &  3    &  5 & 105 & 1030 & 2646.3 & 2436.1 & 0.86  \\
K2L &  5    & 11 &  92 &  903 & 2830.9 & 1948.4 & 0.69  \\
K3R &  3.5  & 10 &  98 &  960 & 2762.4 & 1987.7 & 0.7   \\
K5R &  1    &  7 &  96 &  942 & 2935.1 & 1996.5 & 0.7   \\
K6L & -4    &  7 &  83 &  814 & 3034.1 & 2187.6 & 0.86  \\
K7L &  6.5  &  7 &  69 &  678 & 2414.4 & 1666.9 & 0.59  \\
K8L &  4    & 11 &  79 &  775 & 2741   & 1631.4 & 0.58  \\
K9L &  7    &  6 & 109 & 1070 & 3359   & 2149.7 & 0.76  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
}

\caption{Table in which the \emph{Weight Factors} are depicted as the ratio between the first load peak of the activity and the corresponding one in the average \emph{HIGH100} data. In figure a) the stair descending activity is shown while in figure b) the walking exercise can be seen. In both cases the patient highlighted in red was considered an outlier for the following calculations.}
\label{tab:WF_tab}

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw[red, thick] (a.west) -- ++ (\dimexpr\linewidth-1em,0);
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]