# Striking through multiple column and row in tabular

Tags: tables, strikeout

I am trying to create a table that has multiple strikes through columns and rows, similar to this table
[image: Table]

I have tried this solution [Striking thru a tabular row in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276738/striking-thru-a-tabular-row-in-latex) but it can't produce multiple strikes through. My code looked something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{cancel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{na} = [shape=rectangle,inner sep=0pt]

\newcommand{\myStrikeBegin}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(begin.base)]\node[na](begin){#1};
}

\newcommand{\myStrikeEnd}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(end.base)]\node[na](end){#1};
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
          \draw (begin.west) -- (end.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
            19 & \myStrikeBegin{0} & \myStrikeBegin{15} & 14 \\
            \myStrikeBegin{0} & 5 & 3 & \myStrikeEnd{0} \\
            3 & 2 & 0 & 3\\
            13 & \myStrikeEnd{20} & \myStrikeEnd{0} & 17
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And the result looked like this

[image: myTable]

(I wanted to strike through the 2nd and 4th columns as well as the 3rd row). I have tried to make 3 new similar commands but the resulting table is the same.

Is there any way to do it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @antshar I found that answer that using line tikz produces lines that is not entirely straight and setting out the new command is confusing for me. Maybe I am just not used to using tikz in that way

Comment: @antshar After trying a couple of times, it seems that your link is indeed the answer. Thank you very much. At first, I was very skeptical that it works because it was applied to a matrix, not a table. But it works nonetheless, thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome­

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, this is very easy with `pstricks`:

```
    \documentclass[svgnames]{article}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{xfrac}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{cancel}
    \usepackage{pst-node}
    \usepackage{pst-eucl}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
                19 & \Rnode{A}{0} & 15 & \Rnode{B}{14} \\
                 0 & 5 & 3 & 0 \\
                \Rnode{C}{3} & 2 & 0 & \Rnode{D}{3}\\
                13 & \Rnode{E}{20} & 0 & \Rnode{F}{17}
    \end{tabular}
    \psset{linewidth=0.6pt, linecolor=LightSteelBlue}
    \ncline[nodesepA=-1em, nodesepB=-1em]{A}{E}\ncline[nodesepA=-1em, nodesepB=-1em]{B}{F}\pstLineAB[nodesepA=1em, nodesepB=-1em]{C}{D}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have copied your code but it always produces error somehow. The errors are (Undefined control sequence) and (Undefined color)

Comment: How did you compile? The classic wau is `latex > dvi >dvips >pstopdf`, becasue pdflatex doe not have the tools t make the computations trquired by postscript. Another way is compiling with `xelatex --shell-escape`. The ‘undefined color’ is strange, because pstricks loads `xcolor`, and I have set  the option `[svgnames]` through the \documentclass.